# How can forEach() of a list takes non Consumer<T> expression like list::add

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider the below snippet:

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();               
List<String> strList2 = new ArrayList<>();      

strList.forEach(strList2::add);
```

How this can be possible when `list.forEach()` accepts only `Consumer<T>` which has `void accept(T t)` as method where `list::add` has signature of `boolean accept(T t)`? There is a mismatch in return type right?

Comment: you can provide any function reference that accepts exactly one parameter, no matter what it's name is.

Comment: sidenote, that's a very bad use of `forEach`, better would probably be `strList.addAll(strList2)`

Comment: @Lino Yes true. to illustrate only i used..

Answer (score 6):

```
.forEach(x -> {
    boolean willBeIgnored = strList2.add(x);
    return;
})
```

Comment: That's really impressive I have to say. Fast like a bullet :)

Comment: Wow.. have you been waiting to answer questions? Brilliant..!!

Comment: @Lino ... and ultimately closed as a duplicate and deleted ;)

Comment: @Eugene it always ends like this, always ;)

Comment: One doubt i am getting.. then why we are getting true/false when we are using list.add(T a) as returned value? (I think list.add() and list::add refers to same implementation)

Comment: where is the original thread? can u share link pls?

Comment: @learnAlways JVM just ignores the return value, but you're right. it references the same `add`

Comment: @learnAlways just search for *special void compatibility rule*...

Comment: @Lino Then how compiler is not throwing error in the line `forEach(list::add)` as it doesn't match the `Consumer<T>` signature?

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for the link

Comment: @learnAlways it *does* match the consumer signature, but not in the sense that you would expect

Comment: @learnAlways as said JVM just *ignores* the fact that this method could return any value.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.. This is my first ever question that got answered quickly.. !